# howto safely quit tmux session?

Tags: tmux

Currently I'm using kill-session command, but it looks a bit aggressive and often leave sub-processes running, e.g. I have the following processes running in separate tmux windows:

```
lighttpd -D -f ~/.lighttpd/default.conf # -D don't go to background
foreman # http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/
```

and whenever I quit tmux session using kill-session those processes still running, looks like it send them into background for some reason which is a bit unexpected.

Comment: Considering [there is a](http://superuser.com/questions/399134/howto-safely-quit-tmux-session#comment756295_399143) [new, better question](http://superuser.com/questions/611047/quit-tmux-server-and-end-all-running-processes), I've gone ahead and flagged this for closure as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative to that is to detach tmux and reattach it later. If you stop tmux (through kill-session or any other means), those processes need to be sent to the background (i.e. become children of init) as there is no longer a tmux process that they are children of.

Comment: and how is it possible to kill those processes when exiting tmux instead of sending them to the background?

Comment: Just exit tmux.

Comment: that does not seem to work in my case. i have created a new question: http://superuser.com/questions/611047/quit-tmux-server-and-end-all-running-processes