# quit tmux server and end all running processes

Tags: process, tmux, django

I am running a tmux server configured by tmuxinator. In one pane my django server is running:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

If i quit tmux by calling the `kill-server` command, the `run_gunicorn` command is not killed as i would have expected, but is sent to the background:

```
$ ps aux | grep gunicorn 
alp       3358  1.0  0.1 126988 21728 ?        S    13:06   0:00 python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

How can i quit the tmux server while quiting all running processes within?

Comment: There's a `#{pane_pid}` format variable. You might be able to use `tmux list-panes` in conjunction with this in order to get a list of PIDs in a session (or a single window), then send a `SIGTERM` to them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an alternative by adding a line to my tmuxinator config:

```
pre: pkill -f "^python manage.py run_gunicorn"
```

The `^` at the beginning only matches processes which are starting with that command. Without it you would also kill the tmux process as well.

This does not solve the problem with remaining background processes, but it kills any old processes when restarting the tmux session, which is an acceptable workaround in my case.